# Try catch in switch statement exit option

Tags: java, arrays, loops, switch-statement, try-catch

The issue I am having is when I type in 0 as my menu option (which is the option # to exit the program) the output is:

Invalid choice, please enter a menu option number 0-10

Thank you for using the Gradebook Program, have a nice day.

When it should only be displaying the thank you for using the program message not the invalid choice message.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Tester
      {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
         { 

      Scanner kbReader = new Scanner (System.in);
      boolean loop = true;
      int choice = 0;
      Student array[] = null;
      System.out.printf("%50s", "Welcome to the Gradebook Program!");
      while(loop){
        do
         {
try
{
choice = Student.printMenu();

int numStudents;

switch(choice)
{       
  case 1:
    Gradebook.classInfo();
    numStudents = Gradebook.getNumStudents();
    array = Student.inputStudents(numStudents);
    Student.printGrades(array);
    break;

  case 2:
    array = Student.addStudent(array);
    Student.printGrades(array);
    break;

  case 3:
    int target = Student.getStudentToDelete(array);
    array = Student.deleteStudent(array, target);
    Student.printGrades(array);
    break;

  case 4:
    Student.editStudent(array);
    Student.printGrades(array);
    break;

  case 5:
    Student.printGrades(array);
    break;

  case 6:
    array = Student.inputGrades();
    break;

  case 7:
    Student.outputToFile(array);
    break;

  case 8:
    Student.search(array);
    break;

  case 9: 
    Student.studentHighest(array);
    break;

  case 10:
    Student.assignmentHighest(array);
    break;

  default:        
    System.out.println("\nInvalid choice, please enter a menu option number 0-10");
}

    }
catch(InputMismatchException e)
{
  System.out.println("Error: Invalid input, please enter a menu option number 0-10");11
}
   }
       while(choice != 0);
   loop = false;
    System.out.println("\nThank you for using the Gradebook Program, have a nice day.");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Add a `case 0: break;` in your `switch`.

Comment: What would the while statement change to then?

Comment: It wouldn't. Adding the `case 0` option would stop it going to the `default` case in the switch. It would then exit the loop, display the "Thank you" message, and exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `case 0:` option to your switch:

```
switch(choice)
{   
    case 0: break;
    case 1: ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

Adding the `case 0` option would stop it going to the default case in the switch. It would then exit the loop, display the "Thank you" message, and exit.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement doesn't have a `case 0:`. Thus, it is being directed to the default case. The logic after is then acknowledging the 0 and exiting the loop.

*As mentioned in the comments while I was typing this.*